# How to get html elements by class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get two html buttons of the class `fontsizer`. I need to create a variable, store the buttons in the variable, and then loop through the variable and assign each of the two buttons an event handler for `onclick`. In the end, when a button is clicked, it should run a method named `resizeText`.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function startup() {
    var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer");
    var i;
    alert(fontButtons.length);
    for (i = 0; i < fontButtons.length; i++) {
        fontButtons.elements[i].onclick = resizeText(this);
    }

    function resizeText(objButton) {
        var fontChange;
        fontChange = parseFloat(objButton.value);

        if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
            document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
        }

        var currentFontSize;
        alert("changed");
        currentFontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize);
        currentFontSize = currentFontSize+fontChange;
        document.body.style.fontSize = "currentFontSize+em"
    }
```

From my browser, the `resizeText` function is not run. When I check the size of `fontButtons` before looping, it is `0`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: fontButtons.elements[i] should be fontButtons[i]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handler for onclick is assigned to undefined. This is what the handler should look like

```
fontButtons[i].onclick=function(){resizeText(this);};
```

The reason is that this line of code has several issues

```
fontButtons.elements[i].onclick=resizeText(this);
```

First, `fontButtons` is already a NodeList containing the matched elements on the page, so using `.elements` will not contain any elements. Second, this is going to assign the onclick handler to the result of the resizeText function call. As the function does not return anything, the assignment gets undefined.

Using an anonymous function as the callback to call `resizeText` will allow for a new execution context to be created. The context created by the event handler will bind a new value to `this` allowing the current element that created the event to be sent to the `resizeText` function.

Comment: Still no change.I think the line var fontButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("fontsizer"); doesnt retrieve the elements.Because the alert before the loop shows 0 as the lenght of fontButtons

Comment: @mungaihkamau - Make sure the script is executed after the elements are loaded into the DOM by either placing it at the very bottom of the page just before the closing body tag, or wrapping it in `window.onload = function(){ startup(); };`